# Windows Programs not working properly

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

I'm having this weird issue with Windows programs.

For example, Windows Explorer won't properly work. For example, not showing some filenames etc.

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcU2t.png)

Cmd and powershell experience other, similar issues. When opened they will just show a white screen for a moment and then close.

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edPFN.png)

After I restart my device, this stops temporarily, but after a few hours the issues return.

What could be cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

First, update BIOS, Video and Chipset driver (if one). Best way to do this is to use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App.

**Restart and run DISM.**

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
>
> SFC /SCANNOW
>
> When done, restart and test.

**If DISM does not fix the issue, then run a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

Good luck with this.

Comment: Thank you i will try this out imidiently

Comment: Thank you -  done.